# Datasets not exported/available from my R package

Tags: r, github, export, devtools

Following advice about [NAMESPACE](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html) and [External Data](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) formatting/setup, I have:

A. My data files in mypackage/data/datafilename.RData

[image: folder list of data files]

B. The data script as mypackage/R/data.R with data files individually named and described within that one file, having just changed "itemize" to "describe" and changing the format of those item lines:

[image: data.r screenshot]

C. I've `document()`-ed this, commit-pushed to github, and `install_github` reinstalled locally.

Help for the data files works:

[image: help screenshot]

But I can't access those data, whereas I can access data in other packages using the same method:

[image: data load fail]

Can anyone think why this would be? NAMESPACE doesn't include these as `exports`:

[image: namespace]

But it's autogenerated by `document()` so that's arguably out of my control. By comparison, `mapplots`' NAMESPACE has `exportPattern(".")`

Environment for the package also doesn't include them, but I don't know if this is expected or not, based on lazy loading (which is true):

[image: environment]

Any ideas welcome. I've tried `data(gbm.auto:grids)` with 1, 2 & 3 colons, to no avail. Based on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364061/data-not-exported-from-namespace-in-r) related question (also by me), I get the suspicion that there might be some issue whereby only the last named object in `data.R` is important/accessible?

`usethis` has been created since I've been updating this package and has `use_data` and `create_package` but I'm reluctant to try these out since ostensibly everything in my package should already be in order and I don't want to make things worse.

Thanks in advance. Reprex would be

```
library(devtools)
install_github("SimonDedman/gbm.auto")
```

Edit: to add to this, the datasets available in the installed package are a combo of the full list, some individual, some named in `datalist`:

[image: datalist]

Which contrasts against what's in the working folder and github:

[image: github data folder]

As far as I can see, all the data files are the same format, e.g. when doubleclicked in file explorer they open in RStudio with the right name and same format. gbm.auto/R/data.R file is [here](https://github.com/SimonDedman/gbm.auto/blob/master/R/data.R). Per the last image, the three data files listed in `datalist` can be loaded in R with `library(gbm.auto) data(Juveniles)`, but the other three data files can't. If I delete/rename the existing `datalist` from `/data` and generate a new one with `add_datalist(pkgname = getwd())`, a new file is generated but again it only lists those 3 files, not all 6.

Ugh, goddamn it. Found the issue. The 3 'bad' files had "Rdata" extensions while the 3 good ones had "RData" extensions. Lower case vs capital D. How unbelievably annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data files in `data` must have .R**D**ata extensions, not .R**d**ata

Bug filed [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18015).